# Loaded files of the website with scp, but css files and images are not loaded

Tags: scp

I have copied all the files related to the website to the server using `scp`, but the only css file that I loaded inside css folder on the server is not loaded by the html files. I have checked the path to the stylesheet file in the html files, but it's the same as on local, so it should work. The same problem for images, but not for JavaScript files. What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you check the permissions?

Comment: @CélineAussourd How can I do that?

Comment: you can use `ls -l` and check the owner of the files

Comment: @CélineAussourd In fact, the `images` and the `css` folder have different permissons

Comment: @CélineAussourd What this sequence `drwxr-xr-x` should represent in numbers?

Comment: @CélineAussourd I managed to do that, I changed the mod to 755, which is effectively represented by `drwxr-xr-x`, which means all permissions for the owner and just read and execute permissions for the groups and the rest of the world, right? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the permissions of the files.

You can use the command `ls -l` to check the files permission and files owner.